# Where is the slow start threshhold value set by TCP Reno fast recovery used?

Tags: tcp

From my understanding, TCP Reno basically works as follows (RFC 5681, 3.1, 3.2).
Upon receiving three duplicate acknowledgements, it sets `ssthresh = cwnd/2` and then `cwnd = ssthresh`.
In case of a timeout, `ssthresh = cwnd/2, cwnd = 1` is set and slow start initiated.

It appears to me that the `ssthresh` value set during fast recovery is never used.

Comment: What do you mean by "is never used"? If there is a timeout it will slow start because cwnd < ssthresh. If it recovers it continues congestion avoidance because cwnd >= ssthresh.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it now. So the reason that ssthresh is set to cwnd for fast recovery is so that it continues in congestion avoidance and not slow start.

Comment: Yes, sort of. When cwnd is set to ssthresh after three duplicate acks it is in fast recovery state. It is similar to congestion avoidance. For details I suggest reading the RFC.